# In outlook, is it better to have one large outlook data file or multiple small ones

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

Every few years I create a new Outlook data file for my person info.  Most of these files are around 300MB.  I wanted to see if this actually makes sense in terms of efficiency, etc.

In outlook, is it better to have multiple personal data files or a single large one?  Is there a breakeven point?

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple PST files is a nightmare if you ever move or restore, because you have to go somewhere else to find old emails, and then re-mount your PST files in Outlook, and then you sometimes end up with `archive.pst`, `archive1.pst` and are never entirely sure which PST that email you're looking for is in.

Outlook 2010 has a [default PST size limit of 50gb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982577?wa=wsignin1.0); [but this can be adjusted](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832925?wa=wsignin1.0). I have a 10Gb PST folder (with 3gb in the inbox and the rest over other folders, and up to 30,000 emails in a single folder) and it's just fine.